# How to automate F5 saas_idp template on BigIP from Ansible

Tags: ansible, f5-big-ip

I am deploying a BigIP IdP SAML virtual server in IdP initiated mode thanks to iApps template f5.saas_idp.v1.0.1rc1 based on instruction from https://www.f5.com/pdf/deployment-guides/saml-idp-saas-dg.pdf

It works well from BigIP wizard but I expect to automate and document deployment thanks to a Ansible playbook

```
- name: Deploy {{ idp_host }} with f5.saas_idp iApp template
  bigip_iapp_service:
    name: "saas_idp_{{ idp_host }}"
    template: f5.saas_idp.v1.0.1rc1
    parameters:
      tables:
        - name: saas_apps__saas_choice
          columnNames:
            - app_name
            - app_selection
            - app_sp
            - sp_initiated
          rows:
            - row:
                - "{{ saml_saas_name }}"
                - "/#zendesk#"
                - "{{ saml_saas_sp }}"
                - no # which means "Yes, IdP and SP"
        - name: saas_apps__saas_attributes
          # Empty
      variables:
        - name: options__advanced_mode
          value: yes
        - name: saas_virtual__addr
          value: "{{ idp_address }}"
        - name: saas_virtual__port
          value: 443
        - name: idp_encryption__cert
          value: /Common/{{ idp_host }}_saml_idp_metadata_cert.crt
        - name: idp_encryption__key
          value: /Common/{{ idp_host }}_saml_idp_metadata_cert.key
        - name: saas_virtual__vlan_listening
          value: enabled
        - name: saas_virtual__vlan_selections
          value: /Common/Internal
        - name: saas_virtual__lan_or_wan
          value: LAN
        - name: saas_virtual__tcp_lan_opt
          value: tcp-lan-optimized
        - name: saas_virtual__http
          value: http
        - name: saas_virtual__clientssl
          value: /Common/clientssl_wildcard_2017-2020
        - name: saas_virtual__chainssl
          name: "/#do_not_use#"
        - name: apm__apm_policy
          value: "/#create_new#"
        - name: apm__saml_entity_id_format
          value: url
        - name: apm__saml_entity_id
          value: https://{{ idp_host }}
        - name: apm__aaa_profile
          value: /Common/AAA_myAD
        - name: apm__logging
          value: /Common/default-log-setting
    force: no
    state: present
    strict_updates: no
```

But script fails requiring `saas_virtual__key`, `saas_virtual__cert` and `saas_virtual__chainssl` whereas they are not expected as I provides an existing `saas_virtual__clientssl` in Advanced mode:

```
message":"script did not successfully complete: (can't read "::saas_virtual__key": no such variable
    while executing
"iapp_conf create $cssl_cmd key $::saas_virtual__key cert $::saas_virtual__cert  chain none"
    invoked from within
"subst $substa_out"
    invoked from within
"if { [info exists [set substa_in]] } {
            set substa_out [subst $$substa_in]
            set substa_out [subst $substa_out]
        } else {
..."
    ("uplevel" body line 3)
    invoked from within
"uplevel {
        append ::substa_debug "
$substa_in"
        if { [info exists [set substa_in]] } {
            set substa_out [subst $$substa_in]
 ..."
    (procedure "iapp_substa" line 9)
    invoked from within
"iapp_substa client_ssl_arr($new_client_ssl,$do_chain_cert)"
    invoked from within
"iapp_conf create ltm virtual ${app}_vs  destination [iapp_destination $::saas_virtual__addr $::saas_virtual__port]  ip-protocol tcp  profiles replace-..."
```

Providing these variables does not help, script fails to load because of key password I cannot provide:

```
Error reading key PEM file /Common/wildcard_2017-2020.key
for profile /Common/saas_idp.app/saas_idp_myidphost_client-
ssl: error:0906A068:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad password read
```

So from my point of view, best option is to get template using my existing clientssl profile. How to proceed ? Is there a way to 'debug' iApps template script, at least inspecting variables ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out where was the trap to avoid - Ansible replaced yes value by True python boolean object before submitting variable - so discarding expected string:

```
variables:
  - name: options__advanced_mode
    value: "yes"
```

As a result, advanced mode was not enabled and that is why TCL iApps execution tries to create new clientssl profile:

```
# Client SSL Profile
set new_client_ssl [expr { !$advanced || [iapp_is ::saas_virtual__clientssl "/#create_new#"] }]
set do_chain_cert  [expr { $advanced && \
    [info exists ::saas_virtual__chainssl] && \
    ![iapp_is ::saas_virtual__chainssl "/#do_not_use#"] }]
```

So that iApps template is definitely good... but to ease automation from REST or Ansible, input parameter validation may be improved to submit relevant warning before failing with error message and stack trace.